# Using different relay for refrigerator’s card

Tags: relay, component-selection

My refrigerator’s electonic card has a panasonic Js1**f**-b-12v-f relay on it. I need to change it but I only can find panasonic Js1-b-12v-f on the market. When I check the datasheet of both, I saw a little difference between them. In datasheet, it says the "f" stands for "flux-resistance". The other one (nil) is defined as "sealed".

Is it ok replacing the old one with this new one?

Comment: Flux resistant types allow machine soldering so that the flux liquid doesn't climb into the relay from the terminal under soldering. Sealed types hold also gases which can be important in some environments because arcing can create unwanted chemical reactions. Those reactions can spoil the metallic relay contacts or explode the house as an extreme example. You really should pay attention to the coil current and the ratings of the contacts. Check at least max voltage and max current as the absolute minimum; both of them are as important for acceptable contact life time.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Perhaps  you can snip the protuberance on the corner to vent the relay, and get a bit more life out of it, closer to the OEM part, but I'd not bother since there is also some risk of plastic debris falling into the relay. I don't know why this question was closed, it's a fairly sophisticated question, relatively speaking, and shows research.

Comment: There's an option to vote to reopen,   the close vote seems ill-founded. This is not a question on appliance repair - it's a question about component selection. [detypo'd - RM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the relays are identical with respect to their functioning.

As per Panasonic ['Relay Technical Information'](https://mediac.industry.panasonic.eu/p/2020-08/technical_information_relay_en.pdf?VersionId=hKo6SkEnRJByn6Qd.wx94bwpOO4GnPE2) :

***The flux-resistant type** is constructed so that flux will not enter inside the relay during automatic soldering. However, cleaning is not possible.*

***The sealed type** construction is designed to prevent seeping of flux when soldering and cleaning fluid when cleaning. Harmful substances on the contacts are removed by gas purging before sealing.*

The difference in construction is of importance to the electronic board manufacturer.

Either type will serve equally well as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on lightly edited comments:

Spehro said:

Yes, it will work. Perhaps you can snip the protuberance on the corner to vent the relay, and get a bit more life out of it, closer to the OEM part, but I'd not bother since there is also some risk of plastic debris falling into the relay.

User287001 said:

Check at least max voltage and max current as the absolute minimum; both of them are as important for acceptable contact life time.  You really should pay attention to the coil current and the ratings of the contacts.

Flux resistant types allow machine soldering so that the flux liquid doesn't climb into the relay from the terminal under soldering.

Sealed types hold also gases which can be important in some environments because arcing can create unwanted chemical reactions. Those reactions can spoil the metallic relay contacts or explode the house as an extreme example.
<RM: Unlikely to be relevant in this case.]